# What are some mechanisms or laws that encourage the FBI and CIA to share intelligence in the name of national security?

Tags: united-states, fbi, national-security, intelligence, cia

> *[Wedge: The Secret War Between the FBI and CIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge:_The_Secret_War_Between_the_FBI_and_CIA)*, a nonfiction book by
> American historian and policy analyst Mark Riebling, explores the
> conflict between U.S. domestic law enforcement and foreign
> intelligence. The book presents FBI–CIA rivalry through the prism of
> national traumas—including the Kennedy assassination, Watergate, and
> 9/11—and **argues that the agencies' failure to cooperate has seriously
> endangered U.S. national security.**

What are some mechanisms or laws that encourage the FBI and CIA to share intelligence in the name of national security? Has the U.S. government put any mechanism or law in place to solve this critical issue.

Comment: Really too obvious, but both report to the President, at least, indirectly.

Comment: You also need to research/mention the laws predating 9/11 that were put in place to *prevent* collaboration between CIA and FBI.